# Como funciona o mecanismo de conexões padrão do Django?

Tags: django, conexão

Estou dando manutenção num sistema que usa conexão padrão, via "DATABASES = {", com Oracle 11g. Assim:

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.oracle',
     'USER': 'USUARIO',
     'PASSWORD': 'SENHA',
     'HOST': 'HOST',
     'NAME': 'NAME',
     'CONN_MAX_AGE': 300,
     'OPTIONS': {
         'threaded': True,
         'use_returning_into': False,
     }
 }
}
```

Neste caso o Django automaticamente cria Pool de conexões?

Ou, para cada acesso ao Model o Django cria uma nova conexão?

Como funciona o mecanismo de conexões padrão do Django? Ele gera o Pool ou uma para cada acesso de request ele cria uma nova conexão com o Oracle e mata no fim do response?

Tem um material sobre isto?

Obs.: A minha dúvida é que há uma lentidão, e desconfiou-se que poderia ser o FireWall matando conexões do Pool, o que pensamos gerar esta lentidão. Mas pelo que pesquisei não achei material claro de como funciona as conexões. Também vi os logs não acusa erro recente.

Answer (score 1):

**Preambulo:**
O Django tenta suportar tantos recursos quanto possível em todos os backends de banco de dados. No entanto, nem todos os backends são iguais e a solução foi tomar decisões de design sobre quais recursos devem ser suportados e quais suposições os desenvolvedores (do django) podem fazer com segurança.

**Conexões persistentes:**
As conexões persistentes evitam a sobrecarga de restabelecer uma conexão com o banco de dados em cada request. Eles são controlados pelo parâmetro `CONN_MAX_AGE`, que define a duração máxima de uma conexão. Pode ser definido independentemente para cada banco de dados.

O valor padrão é 0, preservando o comportamento histórico de fechar a conexão com o banco de dados no final de cada request. Para ativar conexões persistentes, configure `CONN_MAX_AGE` para um número positivo (em segundos). Para conexões persistentes ilimitadas, defina-o como `None`.

**Gerenciamento de conexões:**
O Django abre uma conexão quando faz uma consulta ao banco de dados. Ele mantém essa conexão aberta e a reutiliza nos requests subsequentes. O Django fecha a conexão uma vez que excede o tempo máxima definido por `CONN_MAX_AGE` ou quando ela não puder mais ser usada.

Em detalhe, o Django automaticamente abre uma conexão com o banco de dados sempre que ele precisa de uma e já não tem nenhuma - seja porque esta é a primeira conexão, ou porque a conexão anterior foi fechada.

No começo de cada requisição, o Django fecha a conexão se esta atingir sua "idade máxima". Se seu banco de dados encerrar conexões inativas após algum tempo, você deverá definir `CONN_MAX_AGE` para um valor mais baixo, para que o Django não tente usar uma conexão que foi encerrada pelo servidor de banco de dados. (Esse problema pode afetar somente sites de tráfego muito baixo.)

No final de cada requisição, o Django fecha a conexão se ela atingir sua "idade máxima" ou se estiver em um estado de erro irrecuperável. Se algum erro de banco de dados ocorreu durante o processamento das requisições, o Django verifica se a conexão ainda funciona, e fecha se não funcionar. Assim, os erros de banco de dados afetam no máximo um request; se a conexão ficar inutilizável, o próximo request receberá uma nova conexão.

**Ressalvas:**
Como cada thread mantém sua própria conexão, seu banco de dados deve suportar pelo menos tantas conexões simultâneas quanto o número de threads encadeadas.

Às vezes, um banco de dados não é acessado pela maioria de suas views, por exemplo, porque é um banco de dados de um sistema externo ou graças ao armazenamento em cache. Nesses casos, você deve definir `CONN_MAX_AGE` como um valor baixo ou até 0, pois não faz sentido manter uma conexão que provavelmente não será reutilizada. Isso ajudará a manter um número pequeno de conexões simultâneas a este banco de dados.

O servidor de desenvolvimento cria um novo thread para cada request, negando o efeito de conexões persistentes. Não o habilite durante o desenvolvimento.

Quando o Django estabelece uma conexão com o banco de dados, ele configura parâmetros apropriados, dependendo do backend sendo usado. Se você ativar conexões persistentes, essa configuração não será mais repetida em todos os requests. Se você modificar parâmetros, como o `isolation level` ou o `time zone`, deverá restaurar os padrões do Django no final de cada request, forçar um valor apropriado no início de cada request ou desativar as conexões persistentes.

**Referencia:**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/databases/